# Welles Wilder's moving average with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I'm trying to calculate Welles Wilder's type of moving average in a panda dataframe (also called cumulative moving average).

The method to calculate the Wilder's moving average for 'n' periods of series 'A' is:

- Calculate the mean of the first 'n' values in 'A' and set as the mean for the 'n' position.
- For the  following values use the previous mean weighed by (n-1) and the current value of the series weighed by 1 and divide all by 'n'.

My question is: how to implement this in a vectorized way?

I tried to do it iterating over the dataframe (what a I read isn't recommend because is slow). It works, the values are correct, but I get an error

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

and it's probably not the most efficient way of doing it.

My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Building Random sample:
datas = pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-01-31')
np.random.seed(693)
A = np.random.randint(40,60, size=(31,1))
df = pd.DataFrame(A,index = datas, columns = ['A'])

period = 12 # Main parameter
initial_mean = A[0:period].mean() # Equation for the first value.

size = len(df.index)
df['B'] = np.full(size, np.nan)
df.B[period-1] = initial_mean

for x in range(period, size):
    df.B[x] = ((df.A[x] + (period-1)*df.B[x-1]) / period) # Equation for the following values. 

print(df)
```

Comment: For information, [Pandas TA](https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta#indicators-by-category) project has already implemented Wilder's Moving Average.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Pandas [`ewm()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ewm.html#pandas.Series.ewm) method, which behaves exactly as you described when `adjust=False`:

> When adjust is False, weighted averages are calculated recursively as:
>
> ```
> weighted_average[0] = arg[0];
> weighted_average[i] = (1-alpha)*weighted_average[i-1] + alpha*arg[i]
> ```

If you want to do the simple average of the first *period* items, you can do that first and apply `ewm()` to the result.

You can calculate a series with the average of the first *period* items, followed by the other items repeated verbatim, with the formula:

```
pd.Series(
    data=[df['A'].iloc[:period].mean()],
    index=[df['A'].index[period-1]],
).append(
    df['A'].iloc[period:]
)
```

So in order to calculate the Wilder moving average and store it in a new column `'C'`, you can use:

```
df['C'] = pd.Series(
    data=[df['A'].iloc[:period].mean()],
    index=[df['A'].index[period-1]],
).append(
    df['A'].iloc[period:]
).ewm(
    alpha=1.0 / period,
    adjust=False,
).mean()
```

At this point, you can calculate `df['B'] - df['C']` and you'll see that the difference is almost zero (there's some rounding error with float numbers.) So this is equivalent to your calculation using a loop.

You might want to consider skipping the direct average between the first *period* items and simply start applying `ewm()` from the start, which will assume the first row *is* the previous average in the first calculation. The results will be slightly different but once you've gone through a couple of *periods* then those initial values will hardly influence the results.

That would be a way more simple calculation:

```
df['D'] = df['A'].ewm(
    alpha=1.0 / period,
    adjust=False,
).mean()
```